# Swap the positions of grids which are side by side to top and bottom using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two divs(content and an image) which  are side by side in medium screens.

> col-md-6(content) col-md-4(image)

So, when the screen size is changed to small screens and xs screens these div's shouldn't be side by side they should be aligned top and bottom like this :

> image
>
> content

Here's the code that I'm trying in medium screens:

```
<div class="row">
<p class="col-md-6">Content comes here</p>
<img src="someimage" class="col-md-4"/>
```

i.e., the image should be on the top and the content should be below it in small screens.

I'm not able to get the idea how to convert them top and bottom in small screens

I know that grid positions can be changed to left and right by using push and pull but how do I move an element which is on the right side to the top? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please include your *actual* markup in the question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry, I just edited my code and I did mention the code this time. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't pull and push them for `xs` and `sm`, you need just swap them in the code and use `pull-push` for `md`:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-6"><img src="//placehold.it/200x150" class="img-fluid"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-4"><p>Content comes here</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow!, that's a great idea, I never got this thought,  Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

make grid of 12 for small devices.

IMAGE

CONTENT`

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   IMAGE 
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   CONTENT
</div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: But in small screens I want the image to be on the top not the content, sorry for being not clear in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I got your expectation, you can add more custom css:

```
     .custom-row {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .custom-row .img {
        order: 1;
      }

      .custom-row .content {
        order: 2;
      }

      @media (min-width: 992px) {
        .custom-row {
          display: block;
        }

      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <title>Grid Template for Bootstrap</title>
    <style>
      .custom-row {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .custom-row .img {
        order: 1;
      }

      .custom-row .content {
        order: 2;
      }

      @media (min-width: 992px) {
        .custom-row {
          display: block;
        }

      }
    </style>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row custom-row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 content">
          <h1>Bootstrap grid examples</h1>
          <p class="lead">Basic grid layouts to get you familiar with building within the Bootstrap grid system.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 img">
          <img src="http://www.navipedia.net/images/a/a9/Example.jpg" alt="Example">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But in small screens I want the image to be on the top not the content, sorry for being not clear in my question.

Comment: I updated the codes, you just move the second column to the top

Comment: what I want is,  on large and medium screens the content should be on the left side and the image on the right and in small and xs screens the image should be on the top and the content below it.

Comment: Please check my answer again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use pull-right and pull-left classes.
it should work

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-right">
   Content 
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-left">
   image
</div>
</div>
```