# How to reorder columns with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i need to reorder my columns on small devices. i'm trying to use `col-sm-push` and `col-sm-pull` but this not work and i don't understand why.

```
<div class="row no-margin white max-width">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-sm-push-12 col-md-6 no-padding">
    <div class="image">
      A
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-12 col-sm-pull-12 col-md-6 no-padding">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="title">
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        B
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change Bootstrap 3 column order on mobile layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171408/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3-column-order-on-mobile-layout)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swap the positions of grids which are side by side to top and bottom using bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096317/swap-the-positions-of-grids-which-are-side-by-side-to-top-and-bottom-using-boots)

Answer (score 1):

push-pull on `md` screen sizes. push-pull works when they are side by side, which is not the case when screen is `xs`.

You have to set the order that you want on you `xs` screen and for `md` size screen use push-pull

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row no-margin white max-width">
  
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 no-padding col-md-push-6">
    <div class="image">
      B
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-12 col-md-6 no-padding col-md-pull-6">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="title">
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        A
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```